# Android read / access online xml file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I make a android application themed puzzles,
and the answers I put in the xml file,
in folder assets/file.xml, I add also proguard.

after I publish it on google play,
The application turns in reverse engineering by someone,
so that all the answers are there in the xml file unreadable
and distributed on the Internet.

I plan to move this xml file online
eg I put in www.example.com/folder/file.xml to make it more secure.

My question, how to read / access the online xml file?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One method i hvae used is use of webservice to make requests and get xml response. I have achieved this using Soap webservice, i make soap request from my app, and get xml response from server then i can parse the results. This means that you will be storing your answers dynamically in your database, so no one can tamper with them unless they hack database. It is also advisable to use dynamic puzzle question, i.e, store the puzzle questions in an online database so that you can update them without having to go back and update code in the app.